# Renaming Files and Folders recursively deleting everything after the underscore

Tags: file, rename

I tried to build a script to rename files automatically and failed so if anyone can help...

in the same folder i have filenames like :

```
exemple_012345-0abc1def.txt
exemple_012345-0abc1def.config.txt
```

and i would like to delete everything between the first underscore (included) and the first dot so as i get my filenames like :

```
exemple.txt
exemple.config.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your script and specify the type of script.

Comment: Please tell us what type of script you are writing? (shell script/python script/ batch file, etc).

Comment: I have tried with a batch file i found here:             @echo off
setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion
SET Folder="C:\test"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s /a-d /on /b "%Folder%" ^| find "_"') do (
  set N=%%~Na
  call :sub1
  ren %%a !N!%%~Xa
)
goto :eof
:sub1
for /L %%i in (1 1 22) do (
  set S=!N:~%%i^,1!
    if !S! equ _ (
      set N=!N:~0,%%i!
      goto :done
    )
)
:done
goto:eof                                                            but this erase everything after the underscore till the extension (in my exemple : exemple_012345.config.txt I would like to keep .config.txt)

Comment: And i tried with powershell too : $f.name -NewName ($f.name.substring(0,$f.name.indexof('_'))+$f.name.substring($f.name.indexof('.'))) but this just simply not work

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done in python. I am not sure whether this will work perfectly with python in windows.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in files:
        x = fname.index('_')
        y = fname.index('.')
        substr = fname[:x] + fname[y:]
        os.rename(fname, substr)
```

Comment: I checked it on python with windows too and its working fine.